# Android Gradle Errors After project rebuild

Tags: android

My android studio has suddenly lost it, all was working fine a moment ago, after adding a textview to a layout I tried rebuilding it so that I could run it the app on my phone then my terminal was populated with gradle errors below

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Tag <declare-styleable> can not appear inside <declare-styleable>, only <attr>
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-hdpi/values-hdpi.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common'.
Error:(5, 31) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'barLength'.
Error:(7, 34) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'drawableSize'.
Error:(6, 36) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'gapBetweenBars'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.0.1/res/values-sw600dp/values-sw600dp.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout'.
Error:(17, 30) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabGravity'.
Error:(18, 27) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabMode'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/23.0.1/res/values-land/values-land.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout'.
Error:(5, 30) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabGravity'.
Error:(6, 27) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'tabMode'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-large/values-large.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v11/values-v11.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
Error:(71, 44) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectableItemBackground'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v12/values-v12.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v17/values-v17.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml
Error:(5, 35) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
Error:(6, 33) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat'.
Error:(84, 36) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarDivider'.
Error:(85, 43) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
Error:(83, 33) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'.
Error:(86, 37) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionButtonStyle'.
Error:(88, 44) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionMenuTextAppearance'.
Error:(87, 39) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionMenuTextColor'.
Error:(89, 40) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeBackground'.
Error:(90, 43) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeCloseDrawable'.
Error:(91, 45) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionOverflowButtonStyle'.
Error:(110, 45) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'autoCompleteTextViewStyle'.
Error:(102, 41) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'borderlessButtonStyle'.
Error:(111, 31) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonStyle'.
Error:(112, 36) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonStyleSmall'.
Error:(113, 33) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'checkboxStyle'.
Error:(114, 40) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'checkedTextViewStyle'.
Error:(103, 37) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dividerHorizontal'.
Error:(104, 35) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dividerVertical'.
Error:(105, 38) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextBackground'.
Error:(106, 33) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextColor'.
Error:(115, 33) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextStyle'.
Error:(92, 37) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homeAsUpIndicator'.
Error:(107, 49) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listChoiceBackgroundIndicator'.
Error:(95, 48) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listPreferredItemHeightSmall'.
Error:(116, 36) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'radioButtonStyle'.
Error:(117, 34) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ratingBarStyle'.
Error:(100, 44) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectableItemBackground'.
Error:(101, 54) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'selectableItemBackgroundBorderless'.
Error:(118, 32) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'spinnerStyle'.
Error:(96, 48) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAppearanceLargePopupMenu'.
Error:(97, 48) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu'.
Error:(1, -1) Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v22/values-v22.xml
Error:(7, 43) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeShareDrawable'.
/Users/mwangolumbuka/Downloads/NemoVoluminator/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(11, 43) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarItemBackground'.
Error:(13, 37) Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'controlBackground'.
```

Here is the requested gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aubry.chromio.com.nemovoluminator"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

I am a newbie so I have absolutely no idea as to what the errors mean, I could have said its the theme but I have using the custom theme since forever until today after adding a textview and rebuilding the project, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your gradle file !!

Comment: @varunkr i have attached my build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the error, its amazing how something so simple could generate a pile of manure, the error was in my attrs.xml file, before fixing the file was like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
    <attr name="border" format="boolean"></attr>
    <attr name="border_width" format="dimension"></attr>
    <attr name="border_color" format="color"></attr>
    <attr name="shadow" format="boolean"></attr>

//i forgot to end the declare-styleable CircularImageView

    <declare-styleable name="SpinnerTextView">
        <attr name="android:prompt" />
        <attr name="android:entries" />
    </declare-styleable>


<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="circularImageViewStyle" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

I forgot to end the declare-styleable CircularImageView, hence it was overlapping SpinnerTextView, after ending it with  everything worked with no error, my new file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<declare-styleable name="CircularImageView">
    <attr name="border" format="boolean"></attr>
    <attr name="border_width" format="dimension"></attr>
    <attr name="border_color" format="color"></attr>
    <attr name="shadow" format="boolean"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="SpinnerTextView">
        <attr name="android:prompt" />
        <attr name="android:entries" />
    </declare-styleable>


<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="circularImageViewStyle" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Thank You All for taking your time :D, I hope this helps someone in future.